# How to bulk download from arXiv api only for a specific field?

Tags: amazon-s3, computer-science

I'd like to download the source for all of the computer science papers in arXiv.

This question helped with downloading *all* of arXiv using `s3cmd`: [How to download data from Amazon's requester pay buckets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784528/how-to-download-data-from-amazons-requester-pay-buckets)

But even after downloading this, I'm not sure how to tell which paper belongs to which field.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to download *only* cs papers. 
Is that possible using `s3cmd` or any other tool?